# hive not adding file extensions to file names

Tags: hive, hdfs, parquet

I've run the hive query

```
create table my_schema.my_table stored as parquet as select ...
```

It created the table and the files, but i do not see `.parq` file extension next to the files, which is a bit of a problem for me since i wanted to be able to run something like `hdfs -ls -R /path/to/directory | grep .parq` to list all parquet files in a directory.

Is there either a way to filter parquet files regardless of file extension or a way to make hive include the extension?

I have a similar query using impala and there i can see the `.parq` files without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hive will not add extension to the file. You need to do it manually:

```
$ hadoop fs -put /path/to/directory/000000_0 /path/to/directory/data.parquet
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there then a way to identify the files to which i should append the .parquet extension?

Comment: The easier way is - You need to lookup the directory name which is same name as Hive table created with `stored as parquet`.

Comment: That assumes there are no other files in the directory. I am not sure about hive, but in case of impala, that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: True, but why there will be any other file (expect parquet) in a directory belong to table having "stored as parquet" option !